# Nested .properties files

Tags: java, configuration-files

The Documentation of the java.util.Properties-class states:

> A property list can contain another property list as its "defaults"; this second property list is searched if the property key is not found in the original property list.

What's the syntax for that? Or am I misinterpreting something?

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the constructor. You can hand it another Properties object which will be used to retrieve default values.

Comment: Ok. But there is no way to specify "parent"-files inside a properties-File?

Comment: I can't say for sure but I am aware of no other way than using the constructor to provide default values. The syntax of properties is kept so simple that I doubt there is any special syntax for that. And to be honest...it would defeat the purpose...the default is meant as fallback if a value is unset. How is that supposed to work if there were any possbility that the definition of the default might be broken as well?